# How to use this higher order component explained in the Redux Doc?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

Could anyone please help me understand how to use this Higher Order Component explained in the redux document?

I know what Higher Order Component is and I have used this patter several times but I can't figure out how to use this Higher Order Component.

http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/UsingImmutableJS.html#use-a-higher-order-component-to-convert-your-smart-components-immutablejs-props-to-your-dumb-components-javascript-props

Here is what it says...

## Use a Higher Order Component to convert your Smart Component’s Immutable.JS props to your Dumb Component’s JavaScript props

Something needs to map the Immutable.JS props in your Smart Component to the pure JavaScript props used in your Dumb Component. That something is a Higher Order Component (HOC) that simply takes the Immutable.JS props from your Smart Component, and converts them using toJS() to plain JavaScript props, which are then passed to your Dumb Component.

Here is an example of such a HOC:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Iterable } from 'immutable'

export const toJS = WrappedComponent => wrappedComponentProps => {
    const KEY = 0
    const VALUE = 1

    const propsJS = Object.entries(
        wrappedComponentProps
    ).reduce((newProps, wrappedComponentProp) => {
        newProps[wrappedComponentProp[KEY]] = Iterable.isIterable(
            wrappedComponentProp[VALUE]
        )
            ? wrappedComponentProp[VALUE].toJS()
            : wrappedComponentProp[VALUE]
        return newProps
    }, {})

    return <WrappedComponent {...propsJS} />
}
```

And this is how you would use it in your Smart Component:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

import { toJS } from './to-js'
import DumbComponent from './dumb.component'

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        // obj is an Immutable object in Smart Component, but it’s converted to a plain
        // JavaScript object by toJS, and so passed to DumbComponent as a pure JavaScript
        // object. Because it’s still an Immutable.JS object here in mapStateToProps, though,
        // there is no issue with errant re-renderings.
        obj: getImmutableObjectFromStateTree(state)
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(toJS(DumbComponent))
```

By converting Immutable.JS objects to plain JavaScript values within a HOC, we achieve Dumb Component portability, but without the performance hits of using toJS() in the Smart Component.

## Here is my sample code for this!!

### DumbComponent

```
import React from 'react';

const DumbComponent = (props) => {

    const {dataList} = props;

    const renderList = (list) => {

        return list.map((value) => {
            return <li>value</li>
        })

    };

    return (
        <ul>
            {renderList(dataList)}
        </ul>
    )
};

export default DumbComponent;
```

## SmartComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import DumbComponent from './DumbComponent';

//High Order Component
import toJS from './toJS'; 

class SmartComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <DumbComponent dataList={this.props.dataList} />
        );
    }

}


function mapStateToProps(states) {
    return {
        //Let's say this is immutable.
        dataList: state.dataList,
    };
}

//this is how I use Higher Order Component.
//export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SmartComponent);


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(toJS(DumbComponent));
```

## My Question

`export default connect(mapStateToProps)(toJS(DumbComponent));`

This doesn't even export SmartComponent itself. How can the parent component of SmartComponent whose child is DumbComponent use SmartComponent if it is not even exported??

Please tell me how to use this Higher Order Component in the sample code I prepared for this post.

## Update

So, this is the correct way to write?

### SmartComponent

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import DumbComponent from '../components/DumbComponent';

class SmartComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }


  render() {

    return (
      <DumbComponent dataList={this.props.dataList} /> //immutable
    );

  }
}


function mapStateToProps(states) {
  return {
    dataList: state.dataList //immutable
  };
}


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SmartComponent);
```

### DumbComponent

```
import React from 'react';
import toJS from './higher_order_components/toJS';


const DumbComponent = (props) => {

  const {dataList} = props;

  const renderList = (list) => {

    return list.map((value) => {
      return <li>{value}</li>
    })

  };

  return (
    <ul>
      {renderList(dataList)}
    </ul>
  )

};


export default toJS(DumbComponent);
```

Comment: looks good now 

Comment: Thank you! I made another sample code for better understanding and it works as I expect, so I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do something like:

```
let Component = connect(mapStateToProps)(OtherComponent)
```

`Component` is "smart" because it has access to the store. What you're doing in your code is doubling up on smart components.

```
class OtherSmartComponent {
  render { return <DumbComponent {...smartProps} /> }
}
let SmartComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(OtherSmartComponent)
```

That's why in the example Smart Component there is no intermediate Smart Component, just `connect`, `mapStateToProps` and `DumbComponent`.

Might be worth unraveling it all:

```
import DumbComponent from './DumbComponent'
import toJS from './toJS'

let DumbComponentWithJSProps = toJS(DumbComponent)
let SmartComponent = connect(mapStateToProps)(DumbComponentWithJSProps)

export default SmartComponent
```

So really, in your code, SmartComponent isn't really smart. It's just a dumb component that renders another dumb component. The terminology makes this comment seem super harsh.

To clarify your comment:

If you want a component between your connected one and the one that's run through `toJS`, then do that. No need to call `connect` twice:

```
// Dumb.js
import toJS from './toJS

class Dumb { .. }

export default toJS(Dumb)

-----------------------------------

// Smart.js
import Dumb from './Dumb'

class Smart {
  ..methods..
  render() { return <Dumb {...props} /> }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Smart)
```

Comment: I'm still confused... What if I have some instance method in  SmartComponent class above? If I don't export SmartComponent class itself and just do something like this 'export default connect(mapStateToProps)(toJS(DumbComponent));', don't I lose the access to the instance methods of SmartComponent Class?

Comment: Also, I'm confused with the meaning of Smart Component. I thought it means the component which has an access to redux store or uses action creators.

Comment: updated with more info. Smart Component is a fuzzy term.. I guess if your component dispatches actions then it's "smart" too, but the point is that you don't need to `connect` more than once.

Comment: Sorry that I confused you... By these 2 lines, //export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SmartComponent); export default connect(mapStateToProps)(toJS(DumbComponent)); , I didn't mean I want to run these two codes, that why I commented out the first one.

Comment: I'm not confused. The only thing you need to change in your code is the export call in DumbComponent. change `export default DumbComponent` to `export default toJS(DumbComponent)` and all is well. make sense?

Comment: Im getting more clear now about your explanation now! I'll take more time to understand it! Thanks!!

Comment: Yap! I think I got what you mean. I updated with the modified code.